# how to create a file in Mac cloud drive using python

Tags: python, unix, icloud

I am trying to create a file in my cloud drive in a python code. When i create a file at this location"/Users/agauravdeep/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/Untitled.rtf
" using any app, it works but through code, i am unsuccessful so far(no errors though) even after trying through super user.

Code is pretty straightforward

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python

from os.path import expanduser
def createBugsFileInitiallyIfNotPresent():
                    global bugsFileLocation
                    bugsFileLocation =  expanduser("~")+"/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/abc.txt"
                    if(os.path.isfile(bugsFileLocation)):
                            f = open(bugsFileLocation, 'w+')
                            f.write(" dddd ")
```

This works 
Also, vi ~/Library/Mobile\ Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/abcd.txt but when i put quotes around path it doesn't work.

Any suggestions would be very helpful.

Comment: could you try: expanduser("~")+r"/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/abc.txt" instead? (note the r in front of the string)

Comment: You should try debugging this on your own. Drop into an interactive shell (`python` from your terminal) and use `os.path.chdir` to get to where you're trying to go. Use `os.path.listdir` if you're lost on where to go next.

Comment: @Rob.. Thanks but no change in result.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are checking if the file exists, but you say that you want to create it. If you plan to create a new file, remove the if statement:

```
from os.path import expanduser
def createBugsFileInitiallyIfNotPresent():
                global bugsFileLocation
                bugsFileLocation =  expanduser("~")+"/Library/Mobile Documents/com~apple~CloudDocs/abc.txt"
                f = open(bugsFileLocation, 'w+')
                f.write(" dddd ")
```

Comment: wow, you are right. that worked but why doesn't the if works even when there is no such visible file in that folder.

Comment: Because you are checking if the file exists and it does not. So the if clause is not being executed. Oh, you probably was to check if the file does NOT exist and create it, then you should invert the if statement ( if not os.path.isfile(bugsFileLocation)) ).

Comment: my god. Thats the biggest typo ever. I forgot to put not there.... sheeeeeeee. Thanks Rob for pointing out